# Bash script running fine in terminal window, but not when added to autostart

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, bash, lxde

I use a script to start the google voice assistant on my rpi. This script runs fine when I run it from a terminal window, but when I try to run it via the LXDE autostartup nothing happens. It used to work, and after I ran apt-get dist-upgrade it suddenly stopped working...

I am running Raspbian 9. I couldn't find if or where the LXDE autostart creates logs to help me troubleshoot.

This is the content of my script (google_assistant_autostart.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/pi/env/bin/activate

googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project_id "xxxxxxxxxx" --device_model_id "xxxxxxxxxx"$
```

And here's the content of the LXDE-pi autostart:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
@bash /home/pi/google_assistant_autostart.sh
```

I tried removing #!/bin/bash from my script, or @bash from the autostart, but no matter the combination, it just doesn't work.

I would greatly appreciate some help to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried with just @sh instead of @bash?

Comment: I tried, no change.

Comment: Add the #! back to your script so it gets the correct command processor and try moving your command to before the @xscreensaver -no-splash line.